# Jquery assign fucntion to multiple same class selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

i have a code that look like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".numberinput").forceNumeric();
     });


     // forceNumeric() plug-in implementation
     jQuery.fn.forceNumeric = function () {

         return this.each(function () {
             $(this).keydown(function (e) {
                 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

                 if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
                 // numbers   
                     key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
                 // Numeric keypad
                     key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
                 // comma, period and minus, . on keypad
                    key == 190 || key == 188 || key == 109 || key == 110 ||
                 // Backspace and Tab and Enter
                    key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
                 // Home and End
                    key == 35 || key == 36 ||
                 // left and right arrows
                    key == 37 || key == 39 ||
                 // Del and Ins
                    key == 46 || key == 45)
                     return true;

                 return false;
             });
         });
     }
 </script>
```

at document ready, i assign the function like this **$(".numberinput").forceNumeric();**
this will work on one input only. How do i assign the function to multiple input that has same class name?

i have tried this:

```
$(".numberinput").each(function(){ $(this).forceNumeric(); });
```

but this is not working. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin is setup to implicitly work on all elements in the jQuery collection (you can tell by the `return this.each(function(){ })`.

So you should be able to just use `$(".numberinput").forceNumeric()`.

Comment: yes you right, this will work, i just careless, i did miss something, my multiple input available only after popup windows close. I need to assign the forceNumeric function after my popup close, not to document ready..